# Is true && true == false?

Tags: ruby, operator-precedence

Am I missing something or is this a bug in ruby?

```
a = %w(foo bar baz)
a.include? "foo"                # => true
a.size == 3                     # => true
a.include? "foo" && a.size == 3 # => false
```

Comment: I don't know ruby, but precedence botch maybe?  Try `(a.include? "foo") && a.size == 3`, and if it's still wrong, `(a.include? "foo") && (a.size == 3)`.

Comment: It's not a bug at all; Ruby's flexible syntax also means that it follows a different set of rules than you do when determining what the content of a method's parameter list is. How would it magically guess what you meant? The notion that this is a bug in Ruby's logical conditions would be about the *last* thing I would assume.

Comment: [Ruby operators (high to low precedence)](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#table_18.4)

Comment: @devnull: I fail to see how that table would help here. Any clues?

Comment: You are missing something, and that something is knowledge of Ruby syntax. It takes practice, but don't worry - it's much easier than learning Russian.

Comment: I've never understood how people have code behave unexpectedly and think they've discovered "a bug in ruby", in something as fundamental as a boolean `&&`. If this were the case, virtually *no software* written in Ruby would work. What's more likely, that a 20 year old language with *billions* of lines of code written in it has a *fundamental* bug that would break *everything*, or you just don't know what you're doing?

Comment: I've found about 10 bugs in PHP. An 18 years old language with billions of lines of code. Does that count?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
a.include? "foo" && a.size == 3
```

is evaluated as

```
a.include? ("foo" && a.size == 3)
```

and because

```
"foo" && a.size == 3  #=> true
```

this is equivalent to

```
a.include? true
```

which is `false`

Answer (score 4):

> Is `true && true == false`?

No.

```
irb(main):003:0> true && true == false
=> false
```

Answer (score 3):

What you meant to check is

```
a.include?("foo") && a.size == 3
```

Your condition is checking if `"foo" && a.size == 3` (which is `true` because `"foo"` is neither `nil` nor `false`)  is included in the array.

The solution of Zack's comment is correct too, but looking a bit unusual:

```
(a.include? "foo") && a.size == 3
```

One reason why the whole expression is considered the method's argument in case of missing parentheses is you can do:

```
puts 3 + 4 * 5 - 6
```

Comment: I wrote it that way because, like I said, I don't know Ruby, and I was unsure whether `a.include?("foo")` was allowed.